# Switching to Maven in Netbeans

Tags: maven-2, jsf-2, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I am currently trying to migrate an existing web-project in Netbeans 7.0.1 to a Maven-project in Netbeans. The project uses JSF2 and runs on Glassfish 3.1.

I have created a new Maven-project in Netbeans and copied all the files over unmodified. I have then added a maven-dependency for Mojarra as recommended [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The project compiles fine, but when I run it, I get an error 500 due to a `NullPointerException`. The log of Glassfish says this:

```
INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with 
                      the JSP container.
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: I think your problem is in your web.xml and not your pom.xml.  You need to make sure the Facelets Servlet is set up properly.   One quick and easy way to figure this out is to use the Netbeans "new project" feature to create a new project.  Then inspect the setup files there to see what you are missing.

Comment: @AlanObject: Like I said, I copied all the files from the old project unmodified, and that includes the `web.xml`. The other project runs just fine with the identical `web.xml`.